# WooCommerce Subscriptions Current Active Plan

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am working on a simple redirect based on the subscription level of the current user. I have found `has_active_subscription()`, which does a good job of determining if the current user has an active subscription, but I need to know which plan they have (Gold, Silver, Bronze). I can do a `var_dump` of `wcs_get_users_subscriptions($user_id);` , and I can see that there is a meta value that has the ID I need, but I can't for the life of me pull just that value. I can also use this

```
 foreach ($users_subscriptions as $subscription){
  if ($subscription->has_status(array('active'))) {
         echo $subscription->get_id(); 
  }
}
```

but I get a number that does not match the subscription or product ID. The value I'm looking for is under `_linked_pricing_plan` in the below dump.

This the dump:

```
array(1) {
  [14069] => object(WC_Subscription) #8614 (21) { ["order":protected]= > NULL["order_type"] => string(17)
  "shop_subscription" ["cached_payment_count": "WC_Subscription": private] => NULL["data_store_name": protected] => string(12)
  "subscription" ["object_type": protected] => string(12)
  "subscription" ["editable": "WC_Subscription": private] => NULL["extra_data": protected] => array(13) {
    ["billing_period"] => string(0)
    "" ["billing_interval"] => int(1)["suspension_count"] => int(0)["requires_manual_renewal"] => string(4)
    "true" ["cancelled_email_sent"] => bool(false)["trial_period"] => string(0)
    "" ["schedule_trial_end"] => NULL["schedule_next_payment"] => NULL["schedule_cancelled"] => NULL["schedule_end"] => NULL["schedule_payment_retry"] => NULL["schedule_start"] => NULL["switch_data"] => array(0) {}
  } ["valid_date_types": protected] => array(15) {
    [0] => string(5)
    "start" [1] => string(9)
    "trial_end" [2] => string(12)
    "next_payment" [3] => string(13)
    "payment_retry" [4] => string(12)
    "last_payment" [5] => string(9)
    "cancelled" [6] => string(3)
    "end" [7] => string(12)
    "date_created" [8] => string(13)
    "date_modified" [9] => string(9)
    "date_paid" [10] => string(14)
    "date_completed" [11] => string(23)
    "last_order_date_created" [12] => string(20)
    "last_order_date_paid" [13] => string(25)
    "last_order_date_completed" [14] => string(13)
    "payment_retry"
  } ["deprecated_properties": "WC_Subscription": private] => array(9) {
    [0] => string(10)
    "start_date" [1] => string(14)
    "trial_end_date" [2] => string(17)
    "next_payment_date" [3] => string(8)
    "end_date" [4] => string(17)
    "last_payment_date" [5] => string(5)
    "order" [6] => string(15)
    "payment_gateway" [7] => string(23)
    "requires_manual_renewal" [8] => string(16)
    "suspension_count"
  } ["status_transition": protected] => bool(false)["data": protected] => array(46) {
    ["parent_id"] => int(14068)["status"] => string(6)
    "active" ["currency"] => string(3)
    "USD" ["version"] => string(5)
    "7.6.0" ["prices_include_tax"] => bool(false)["date_created"] => object(WC_DateTime) #8584 (4) { ["utc_offset":protected]= > int(0)["date"] => string(26)
    "2023-04-20 16:56:37.000000" ["timezone_type"] => int(3)["timezone"] => string(16)
    "America/New_York"
  } ["date_modified"] => object(WC_DateTime) #8586 (4) { ["utc_offset":protected]= > int(0)["date"] => string(26)
  "2023-04-20 12:56:48.000000" ["timezone_type"] => int(3)["timezone"] => string(16)
  "America/New_York"
} ["discount_total"] => string(1)
"0" ["discount_tax"] => string(1)
"0" ["shipping_total"] => string(1)
"0" ["shipping_tax"] => string(1)
"0" ["cart_tax"] => string(1)
"0" ["total"] => string(6)
"800.00" ["total_tax"] => string(1)
"0" ["customer_id"] => int(15)["order_key"] => string(22)
"wc_order_cbJn1OLuGQkjv" ["billing"] => array(11) {
  ["first_name"] => string(5)
  "Bobby" ["last_name"] => string(5)
  "Brown" ["company"] => string(0)
  "" ["address_1"] => string(18)
  "5612 Richmond Ave." ["address_2"] => string(0)
  "" ["city"] => string(6)
  "Dallas" ["state"] => string(2)
  "TX" ["postcode"] => string(5)
  "75206" ["country"] => string(2)
  "US" ["email"] => string(21)
  "aaronpage@hotmail.com" ["phone"] => string(12)
  "555-555-5555"
} ["shipping"] => array(10) {
  ["first_name"] => string(0)
  "" ["last_name"] => string(0)
  "" ["company"] => string(0)
  "" ["address_1"] => string(0)
  "" ["address_2"] => string(0)
  "" ["city"] => string(0)
  "" ["state"] => string(0)
  "" ["postcode"] => string(0)
  "" ["country"] => string(0)
  "" ["phone"] => string(0)
  ""
} ["payment_method"] => string(24)
"ppcp-credit-card-gateway" ["payment_method_title"] => string(12)
"Credit Cards" ["transaction_id"] => string(0)
"" ["customer_ip_address"] => string(12)
"45.21.19.190" ["customer_user_agent"] => string(80)
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0" ["created_via"] => string(8)
"checkout" ["customer_note"] => string(0)
"" ["date_completed"] => NULL["date_paid"] => NULL["cart_hash"] => string(0)
"" ["order_stock_reduced"] => bool(false)["download_permissions_granted"] => bool(true)["new_order_email_sent"] => bool(false)["recorded_sales"] => bool(false)["recorded_coupon_usage_counts"] => bool(false)["billing_period"] => string(4)
"year" ["billing_interval"] => string(1)
"1" ["suspension_count"] => int(0)["requires_manual_renewal"] => bool(false)["cancelled_email_sent"] => string(0)
"" ["trial_period"] => string(0)
"" ["schedule_trial_end"] => NULL["schedule_next_payment"] => object(WC_DateTime) #8589 (4) { ["utc_offset":protected]= > int(0)["date"] => string(26)
"2024-04-20 12:56:37.000000" ["timezone_type"] => int(3)["timezone"] => string(16)
"America/New_York"
} ["schedule_cancelled"] => NULL["schedule_end"] => NULL["schedule_payment_retry"] => NULL["schedule_start"] => object(WC_DateTime) #8594 (4) { ["utc_offset":protected]= > int(0)["date"] => string(26)
"2023-04-20 12:56:37.000000" ["timezone_type"] => int(3)["timezone"] => string(16)
"America/New_York"
} ["switch_data"] => array(0) {}
} ["legacy_datastore_props": protected] => array(5) {
  [0] => string(15)
  "_recorded_sales" [1] => string(29)
  "_recorded_coupon_usage_counts" [2] => string(29)
  "_download_permissions_granted" [3] => string(20)
  "_order_stock_reduced" [4] => string(21)
  "_new_order_email_sent"
} ["items": protected] => array(0) {} ["items_to_delete": protected] => array(0) {} ["cache_group": protected] => string(6)
"orders" ["id": protected] => int(14069)["changes": protected] => array(0) {} ["object_read": protected] => bool(true)["default_data": protected] => array(46) {
  ["parent_id"] => int(0)["status"] => string(0)
  "" ["currency"] => string(0)
  "" ["version"] => string(0)
  "" ["prices_include_tax"] => bool(false)["date_created"] => NULL["date_modified"] => NULL["discount_total"] => int(0)["discount_tax"] => int(0)["shipping_total"] => int(0)["shipping_tax"] => int(0)["cart_tax"] => int(0)["total"] => int(0)["total_tax"] => int(0)["customer_id"] => int(0)["order_key"] => string(0)
  "" ["billing"] => array(11) {
    ["first_name"] => string(0)
    "" ["last_name"] => string(0)
    "" ["company"] => string(0)
    "" ["address_1"] => string(0)
    "" ["address_2"] => string(0)
    "" ["city"] => string(0)
    "" ["state"] => string(0)
    "" ["postcode"] => string(0)
    "" ["country"] => string(0)
    "" ["email"] => string(0)
    "" ["phone"] => string(0)
    ""
  } ["shipping"] => array(10) {
    ["first_name"] => string(0)
    "" ["last_name"] => string(0)
    "" ["company"] => string(0)
    "" ["address_1"] => string(0)
    "" ["address_2"] => string(0)
    "" ["city"] => string(0)
    "" ["state"] => string(0)
    "" ["postcode"] => string(0)
    "" ["country"] => string(0)
    "" ["phone"] => string(0)
    ""
  } ["payment_method"] => string(0)
  "" ["payment_method_title"] => string(0)
  "" ["transaction_id"] => string(0)
  "" ["customer_ip_address"] => string(0)
  "" ["customer_user_agent"] => string(0)
  "" ["created_via"] => string(0)
  "" ["customer_note"] => string(0)
  "" ["date_completed"] => NULL["date_paid"] => NULL["cart_hash"] => string(0)
  "" ["order_stock_reduced"] => bool(false)["download_permissions_granted"] => bool(false)["new_order_email_sent"] => bool(false)["recorded_sales"] => bool(false)["recorded_coupon_usage_counts"] => bool(false)["billing_period"] => string(0)
  "" ["billing_interval"] => int(1)["suspension_count"] => int(0)["requires_manual_renewal"] => string(4)
  "true" ["cancelled_email_sent"] => bool(false)["trial_period"] => string(0)
  "" ["schedule_trial_end"] => NULL["schedule_next_payment"] => NULL["schedule_cancelled"] => NULL["schedule_end"] => NULL["schedule_payment_retry"] => NULL["schedule_start"] => NULL["switch_data"] => array(0) {}
} ["data_store": protected] => object(WC_Data_Store) #8582 (4) { ["instance":"WC_Data_Store":private]= > object(WCS_Subscription_Data_Store_CPT) #8583 (7) { ["subscription_internal_meta_keys":protected]= > array(7) {
  [0] => string(19)
  "_schedule_trial_end" [1] => string(22)
  "_schedule_next_payment" [2] => string(19)
  "_schedule_cancelled" [3] => string(13)
  "_schedule_end" [4] => string(23)
  "_schedule_payment_retry" [5] => string(25)
  "_subscription_switch_data" [6] => string(15)
  "_schedule_start"
} ["subscription_meta_keys_to_props": protected] => array(13) {
  ["_billing_period"] => string(14)
  "billing_period" ["_billing_interval"] => string(16)
  "billing_interval" ["_suspension_count"] => string(16)
  "suspension_count" ["_cancelled_email_sent"] => string(20)
  "cancelled_email_sent" ["_requires_manual_renewal"] => string(23)
  "requires_manual_renewal" ["_trial_period"] => string(12)
  "trial_period" ["_schedule_trial_end"] => string(18)
  "schedule_trial_end" ["_schedule_next_payment"] => string(21)
  "schedule_next_payment" ["_schedule_cancelled"] => string(18)
  "schedule_cancelled" ["_schedule_end"] => string(12)
  "schedule_end" ["_schedule_payment_retry"] => string(22)
  "schedule_payment_retry" ["_schedule_start"] => string(14)
  "schedule_start" ["_subscription_switch_data"] => string(11)
  "switch_data"
} ["internal_meta_keys": protected] => array(84) {
  [0] => string(10)
  "_parent_id" [1] => string(7)
  "_status" [2] => string(9)
  "_currency" [3] => string(8)
  "_version" [4] => string(19)
  "_prices_include_tax" [5] => string(13)
  "_date_created" [6] => string(14)
  "_date_modified" [7] => string(15)
  "_discount_total" [8] => string(13)
  "_discount_tax" [9] => string(15)
  "_shipping_total" [10] => string(13)
  "_shipping_tax" [11] => string(9)
  "_cart_tax" [12] => string(6)
  "_total" [13] => string(10)
  "_total_tax" [14] => string(12)
  "_customer_id" [15] => string(10)
  "_order_key" [16] => string(8)
  "_billing" [17] => string(9)
  "_shipping" [18] => string(15)
  "_payment_method" [19] => string(21)
  "_payment_method_title" [20] => string(15)
  "_transaction_id" [21] => string(20)
  "_customer_ip_address" [22] => string(20)
  "_customer_user_agent" [23] => string(12)
  "_created_via" [24] => string(14)
  "_customer_note" [25] => string(15)
  "_date_completed" [26] => string(10)
  "_date_paid" [27] => string(10)
  "_cart_hash" [28] => string(20)
  "_order_stock_reduced" [29] => string(29)
  "_download_permissions_granted" [30] => string(21)
  "_new_order_email_sent" [31] => string(15)
  "_recorded_sales" [32] => string(29)
  "_recorded_coupon_usage_counts" [33] => string(15)
  "_billing_period" [34] => string(17)
  "_billing_interval" [35] => string(17)
  "_suspension_count" [36] => string(24)
  "_requires_manual_renewal" [37] => string(21)
  "_cancelled_email_sent" [38] => string(13)
  "_trial_period" [39] => string(19)
  "_schedule_trial_end" [40] => string(22)
  "_schedule_next_payment" [41] => string(19)
  "_schedule_cancelled" [42] => string(13)
  "_schedule_end" [43] => string(23)
  "_schedule_payment_retry" [44] => string(15)
  "_schedule_start" [45] => string(12)
  "_switch_data" [46] => string(14)
  "_customer_user" [48] => string(15)
  "_order_currency" [49] => string(19)
  "_billing_first_name" [50] => string(18)
  "_billing_last_name" [51] => string(16)
  "_billing_company" [52] => string(18)
  "_billing_address_1" [53] => string(18)
  "_billing_address_2" [54] => string(13)
  "_billing_city" [55] => string(14)
  "_billing_state" [56] => string(17)
  "_billing_postcode" [57] => string(16)
  "_billing_country" [58] => string(14)
  "_billing_email" [59] => string(14)
  "_billing_phone" [60] => string(20)
  "_shipping_first_name" [61] => string(19)
  "_shipping_last_name" [62] => string(17)
  "_shipping_company" [63] => string(19)
  "_shipping_address_1" [64] => string(19)
  "_shipping_address_2" [65] => string(14)
  "_shipping_city" [66] => string(15)
  "_shipping_state" [67] => string(18)
  "_shipping_postcode" [68] => string(17)
  "_shipping_country" [69] => string(15)
  "_shipping_phone" [70] => string(15)
  "_completed_date" [71] => string(10)
  "_paid_date" [72] => string(10)
  "_edit_lock" [73] => string(10)
  "_edit_last" [74] => string(14)
  "_cart_discount" [75] => string(18)
  "_cart_discount_tax" [76] => string(15)
  "_order_shipping" [77] => string(19)
  "_order_shipping_tax" [78] => string(10)
  "_order_tax" [79] => string(12)
  "_order_total" [86] => string(14)
  "_order_version" [90] => string(15)
  "_payment_tokens" [91] => string(22)
  "_billing_address_index" [92] => string(23)
  "_shipping_address_index" [103] => string(25)
  "_subscription_switch_data"
} ["internal_data_store_key_getters": protected] => array(5) {
  ["_download_permissions_granted"] => string(28)
  "download_permissions_granted" ["_recorded_sales"] => string(14)
  "recorded_sales" ["_recorded_coupon_usage_counts"] => string(28)
  "recorded_coupon_usage_counts" ["_order_stock_reduced"] => string(19)
  "order_stock_reduced" ["_new_order_email_sent"] => string(20)
  "new_order_email_sent"
} ["meta_type": protected] => string(4)
"post" ["object_id_field_for_meta": protected] => string(0)
"" ["must_exist_meta_keys": protected] => array(0) {}
} ["stores": "WC_Data_Store": private] => array(46) {
  ["coupon"] => string(24)
  "WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT" ["customer"] => string(22)
  "WC_Customer_Data_Store" ["customer-download"] => string(31)
  "WC_Customer_Download_Data_Store" ["customer-download-log"] => string(35)
  "WC_Customer_Download_Log_Data_Store" ["customer-session"] => string(30)
  "WC_Customer_Data_Store_Session" ["order"] => string(23)
  "WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT" ["order-refund"] => string(30)
  "WC_Order_Refund_Data_Store_CPT" ["order-item"] => string(24)
  "WC_Order_Item_Data_Store" ["order-item-coupon"] => string(31)
  "WC_Order_Item_Coupon_Data_Store" ["order-item-fee"] => string(28)
  "WC_Order_Item_Fee_Data_Store" ["order-item-product"] => string(32)
  "WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store" ["order-item-shipping"] => string(33)
  "WC_Order_Item_Shipping_Data_Store" ["order-item-tax"] => string(28)
  "WC_Order_Item_Tax_Data_Store" ["payment-token"] => string(27)
  "WC_Payment_Token_Data_Store" ["product"] => string(25)
  "WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT" ["product-grouped"] => string(33)
  "WC_Product_Grouped_Data_Store_CPT" ["product-variable"] => string(34)
  "WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT" ["product-variation"] => string(35)
  "WC_Product_Variation_Data_Store_CPT" ["shipping-zone"] => string(27)
  "WC_Shipping_Zone_Data_Store" ["webhook"] => string(21)
  "WC_Webhook_Data_Store" ["order-item-line_item_removed"] => string(32)
  "WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store" ["order-item-line_item_switched"] => string(32)
  "WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store" ["order-item-coupon_pending_switch"] => string(31)
  "WC_Order_Item_Coupon_Data_Store" ["order-item-fee_pending_switch"] => string(28)
  "WC_Order_Item_Fee_Data_Store" ["subscription"] => string(31)
  "WCS_Subscription_Data_Store_CPT" ["product-variable-subscription"] => string(35)
  "WCS_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT" ["product-subscription_variation"] => string(35)
  "WC_Product_Variation_Data_Store_CPT" ["order-item-line_item_pending_switch"] => string(32)
  "WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store" ["report-revenue-stats"] => string(63)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Orders\Stats\DataStore" ["report-orders"] => string(57)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Orders\DataStore" ["report-orders-stats"] => string(63)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Orders\Stats\DataStore" ["report-products"] => string(59)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Products\DataStore" ["report-variations"] => string(61)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Variations\DataStore" ["report-products-stats"] => string(65)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Products\Stats\DataStore" ["report-variations-stats"] => string(67)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Variations\Stats\DataStore" ["report-categories"] => string(61)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Categories\DataStore" ["report-taxes"] => string(56)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Taxes\DataStore" ["report-taxes-stats"] => string(62)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Taxes\Stats\DataStore" ["report-coupons"] => string(58)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Coupons\DataStore" ["report-coupons-stats"] => string(64)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Coupons\Stats\DataStore" ["report-downloads"] => string(60)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Downloads\DataStore" ["report-downloads-stats"] => string(66)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Downloads\Stats\DataStore" ["admin-note"] => string(44)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\Notes\DataStore" ["report-customers"] => string(60)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Customers\DataStore" ["report-customers-stats"] => string(66)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Customers\Stats\DataStore" ["report-stock-stats"] => string(62)
  "Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Stock\Stats\DataStore"
} ["current_class_name": "WC_Data_Store": private] => string(31)
"WCS_Subscription_Data_Store_CPT" ["object_type": "WC_Data_Store": private] => string(12)
"subscription"
} ["meta_data": protected] => array(6) {
  [0] => object(WC_Meta_Data) #8593 (2) { ["current_data":protected]= > array(3) {
    ["id"] => int(79483)["key"] => string(13)
    "is_vat_exempt" ["value"] => string(2)
    "no"
  } ["data": protected] => array(3) {
    ["id"] => int(79483)["key"] => string(13)
    "is_vat_exempt" ["value"] => string(2)
    "no"
  }
} [1] => object(WC_Meta_Data) #8588 (2) { ["current_data":protected]= > array(3) {
  ["id"] => int(79484)["key"] => string(16)
  "_fm_plan_ordered" ["value"] => string(5)
  "14055"
} ["data": protected] => array(3) {
  ["id"] => int(79484)["key"] => string(16)
  "_fm_plan_ordered" ["value"] => string(5)
  "14055"
}
} [2] => object(WC_Meta_Data) #8637 (2) { ["current_data":protected]= > array(3) {
  ["id"] => int(79485)["key"] => string(11)
  "_listing_id" ["value"] => array(6) {
    [0] => string(1)
    "0" [1] => int(14071)[2] => int(14077)[3] => int(14071)[4] => int(14077)[5] => int(14077)
  }
} ["data": protected] => array(3) {
  ["id"] => int(79485)["key"] => string(11)
  "_listing_id" ["value"] => array(6) {
    [0] => string(1)
    "0" [1] => int(14071)[2] => int(14077)[3] => int(14071)[4] => int(14077)[5] => int(14077)
  }
}
} [3] => object(WC_Meta_Data) #8590 (2) { ["current_data":protected]= > array(3) {
  ["id"] => int(79486)["key"] => string(9)
  "_fm_plans" ["value"] => string(5)
  "14055"
} ["data": protected] => array(3) {
  ["id"] => int(79486)["key"] => string(9)
  "_fm_plans" ["value"] => string(5)
  "14055"
}
} [4] => object(WC_Meta_Data) #8592 (2) { ["current_data":protected]= > array(3) {
  ["id"] => int(79492)["key"] => string(20)
  "_linked_pricing_plan" ["value"] => string(5)
  "13714"
} ["data": protected] => array(3) {
  ["id"] => int(79492)["key"] => string(20)
  "_linked_pricing_plan" ["value"] => string(5)
  "13714"
}
} [5] => object(WC_Meta_Data) #8591 (2) { ["current_data":protected]= > array(3) {
  ["id"] => int(79506)["key"] => string(16)
  "payment_token_id" ["value"] => string(8)
  "8vpjqdjd"
} ["data": protected] => array(3) {
  ["id"] => int(79506)["key"] => string(16)
  "payment_token_id" ["value"] => string(8)
  "8vpjqdjd"
}
}
}
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried this, and a few variations `$pricing_plan = $array[0]->get_meta('_linked_pricing_plan');` and

`if (isset($data['_linked_pricing_plan'])) { $linked_pricing_plan = $data['_linked_pricing_plan']; }`